# What is the alternative of service broker in azure to get notification on insert or update db?

Tags: .net, database, azure, model-view-controller, notifications

I need to get notification when the user insert or update on database on azure server ... this could happen be Enable_Broker in IIS server. Unfortunately azure does not support Service Broker... Is there Alternative, What I can use to get notification on update or insert database..

Comment: Oh fantastic! After I've just spent 3 hours researching and planning for using this :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is one of the limitations of SQL Azure (i suppose you mean SQL Azure. You may vote for the feature on the [official UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/423275-enable-sql-service-broker-in-sql-azure). Alternative should be use of full-fledged SQL Server on the Azure VM or use of some kind of messaging queue like [Azure Storage Queue](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) (when updating/creating/etc, send the message to the queue as a notification, and a receiver on the other end).

**From comments section:**

For use of Storage Queues, there is an [official tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) that works very well. Except configuration, you need **"Insert a message into a queue"** and **"De-queue the next message"** sections.
So, your solution may look like:
Your app is doing the change in the database => once it completes, app inserts the message into the queue => once it is done, that message should be de-queued on the other side with other application (which is the side that should be notified about changes).

Comment: Thanks... Yes I mean SQL Azure.
Do you recommend any demo on Azure storage Queue when update or insert.
Thank u again.

Comment: @J.Hamwi what is the language you use?

Comment: I use C# programming language

Comment: @J.Hamwi i added the "from comments section" section. Please review if that helps.

Comment: I am trying to implement it but its hard little bit

Comment: Maybe to use full-fledged SQL Server on the virtual machine will be more good solution for you?

Comment: Is it possible to use trigger instead of that

Comment: If using VM - yes. If using SQL Azure, i think no. There is another service called Azure Functions, but it does not support yet SQL Azure. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference/

Comment: Microsoft has just released Azure SQL "Manage Instance" in preview. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has just released "Managed Instance" in preview which supports Service Broker with some limitations (ex: cross-instance service broker is not supported).

> Azure SQL Database Managed Instance (preview) is a new capability of
>   Azure SQL Database, providing near 100% compatibility with SQL Server
>   on-premises, providing a native virtual network (VNet) implementation
>   that addresses common security concerns, and a business model
>   favorable for on-premises SQL Server customers. Managed Instance
>   allows existing SQL Server customers to lift and shift their
>   on-premises applications to the cloud with minimal application and
>   database changes. At the same time, Managed Instance preserves all
>   PaaS capabilities (automatic patching and version updates, backup,
>   high-availability), that drastically reduces management overhead and
>   TCO.

- [Overview of Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance)
- [Service Broker Differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-transact-sql-information#service-broker)