# Service Broker on SQL Azure

Tags: signalr, azure-sql-database, service-broker, sqldependency

I've implemented a notifications module using SignalR. It works well in the test environment but out production application is in Microsoft Azure with SQL Azure. I can't enable Service Broker there. Is there any alternative to this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a limitation of Azure SQL. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/37640879/474702

Comment: yeah, thanks by the way

Comment: Were you able to get around this limitation?

Comment: No, I couldn't. after sometime team decided to wait until Service Broker is something similar to that is released in Azure SQL.

Comment: me again, they now offer SQL Server [managed instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-transact-sql-information#service-broker) in Azure, with some Service Broker support

Comment: @reckface Our database is hosted in SQL Azure. Still SQL Service Broker is not available there. Is there a substitute method to push notifications to an AngularJS Web App.