# Tracking table changes in ASP.NET core 2 and EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqldependency

I am working on integrations so I am building an api in `.NET Core 2` and `Entity Framework 7` for a system that was built in `ASP.NET MVC 5` and `EF 6` to communicate with other `API's`. Here is an image of what it looks like

[image]

I would like my `asp.net core 2` API to listen to changes in `SQL Server` rather than being notified by the `MVC` app every time a change happens.

I read this article here [sqldependency](https://blog.jsinh.in/monitoring-data-change-using-sqldependency-and-c/#.Wept_miPLD5).  `SQLdependency` is around 15 years old, is this still the standard way of listening to DB changes or is there another way I could do this?

Comment: Be cautious before using SqlDependency. It requires Service Broker and if you're using SQL Azure - or think you may - it isn't available unless you have a managed instance - so first check you can even enable it before writing any code!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Thanks! So I decided not to go this route. Also it was a private server not a chance of using azure.

Comment: I wasted way too much time reading all about SqlDependency yesterday, writing code then found I can’t even use it. Interesting to see how it works though - so the day after I’m glad I at least understand it now! Wasn’t happy yesterday though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ado.net were a class `SqlDependency` for that kind of notification, on `EF` do not supported, but here are some samples

https://web.archive.org/web/20150916155640/https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-SqlDependency-5c0da0b3

www.codeproject.com/Articles/496484/SqlDependency-with-Entity-Framework

And in this question talk about some issues

[Is SqlDependency supported in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657073/sqldependency-and-net-core)