# Azure DB using SqlTabledependency

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

Hi I'm new to using SQLTableDependency and was able to connect to the database locally via c#. I want to connect to the database that we have on azure and thought I would be simply to set the connection string, but when running it I get this error:

TableDependency.SqlClient.Exceptions.ImpossibleOpenSqlConnectionException: 'Impossible open db connection using the following connection string 'Data Source

Comment: Sql dependency requires Service broker, which is not supported? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640879/what-is-the-alternative-of-service-broker-in-azure-to-get-notification-on-insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need broker service to be running to detect changes using SqlTableDependency. Unfortunately, SQL Azure Database does not support Service Broker. SQL Dependency is not supported on Azure SQL Database.

UPDATE: The new Azure Managed Instance supports Service Broker as mentioned [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/03/07/what-is-azure-sql-database-managed-instance-2/).