# Join sqldependency and SignalR with asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, sqldependency

How can I Join sqldependency and SignalR with asp.net core to get a notification if there is any change in data in the database?

Comment: Caution: If you're planning on using SqlDependency with SQL Azure it won't work unless you have your own managed instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640879