# Using SQL Server Service Broker with .NET 6 and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET 6 web API and a SQL Server hosted on Azure, and I need to use the SQL Server service broker to receive and capture notifications of table changes in the database. This way, I avoid making several requests to the database to find out if the expected data has been included. However, when I start SqlDependency, the following error is returned: "Statement 'RECEIVE MSG' is not supported in this version of SQL Server." I really need this feature that is present in the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package.

I am initializing SqlDependency in program.cs as follows:

```
SqlDependency.Start(builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:db"]);
```

The code where I am using SqlDependency looks like this:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Game>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);

var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
dependency.OnChange += (sender, args) =>
{
tcs.TrySetCanceled(cancellationToken);
};
```

This way, I can capture database notifications and perform the necessary actions.

Does anyone know why SqlDependency is not working and can suggest an alternative package? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Are you using Azure SQL Database or a different SQL Server platform?

Comment: @DanGuzman I am using azure SQL Database

Comment: Azure SQL Database does not support Service Broker, which is a needed for SQL Dependency. However, It is available on SQL Managed Instance and Azure SQL VM. I'm not aware of an alternative without polling.

Comment: Although not a direct alternative to SqlDependency, you could a queueing mechanism for notifications. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640879/what-is-the-alternative-of-service-broker-in-azure-to-get-notification-on-insert.

Comment: @DanGuzman I understand, thank you very much for responding. I'll wait, maybe someone will come up with an alternative without having to change the resource in Azure.

Comment: @DanGuzman Any other queue or storage service won't be efficient for me. What I'm doing uses WebSockets and needs to work in real-time. Anything other than direct SQL to the API will cost in efficiency.

Comment: I wouldn't make assumptions about the efficiency of using external queues without actually trying it. Service Broker uses queues too, just embedded in the database.

Comment: It's not great, but you can use triggers to call some external code that pushes updates to your API. I'm pretty sure you don't need real-time monitoring for stuff inside SQL though.

Comment: Can't the thing that changes your tables notify your websocket thing instead?

Comment: You could look into event grid with [sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/azure-sql-database-external-rest-endpoints-integration-public-preview/) , combined with triggers that @siggemannen suggests

Comment: These are interesting approaches, I will try to implement them, whoever has more ideas, keep suggesting, thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Dan Guzman's comment is useful, and I also found this. And I have another suggestion for you.

I found Azure SQL trigger. The Azure SQL Trigger binding uses a polling loop to check for changes, triggering the user function when changes are detected.

[Azure SQL bindings for Azure Functions overview (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Comment: The Azure SQL Trigger is triggered using a polling loop, just as you commented, and therefore it is not real-time. I can adjust it to work almost in real-time, but I believe there will still be some latency.